# pd.merge is not merging on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge these 2 dataframes below on the column retweeting_id

```
                retweeting_id           retweeting_username     retweeting_followers_count
207857          822215673812119553      WhiteHouse              26139914
```

```
        id                      user_id  retweet_count      tweet                              prediction   retweeting_id   username    
4682    1341442941642928129     64932923    191     RT @WhiteHouse: Over 80% of Americans say they...   2   8.222157e+17    Erika   
4683    1341443049067479041     64932923    332     Hope—and help—are on the way!\n\n"The first sh...   2   8.222157e+17    Erika   
5764    1339008184997064705     232598875   694     "Yesterday, the United States witnessed a medi...   1   8.222157e+17    Wm R Collie IV MD   
10065   1338931792800325634     1105109168  297     "Yesterday, the United States witnessed a medi...   1   8.222157e+17    President-elect
```

but when I use

```
df1 = pd.merge(test2, test1, on= 'retweeting_id')
```

I get an empty dataframe. I think the scientific notation in the second dataframe is messing it up but I know the numbers are the same because I'm using

```
test2 = df_merge2[(df_merge2['retweeting_id'] == 822215673812119553  )]
```

to get the second dataframe. Any ideas on how to get these two to merge, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: in other words, your question is mostly about scientific notation and how to convert them

Comment: yes but when i convert the retweeting_id column to int it changes to -2147483648 for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by converting to string using

```
test2.retweeting_id = test2.retweeting_id.map(lambda x: '{:.0f}'.format(x))
```

on both dataframes and now they merge correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the retweeting_id to an integer on the second data frame. Then, try to merge again.

Comment: I tried using this line of code test2['retweeting_id'] = test2['retweeting_id'].map(np.uint64) but then it changes the number to 822215673812119552 which is -1 the actual number that I know it is because I'm using test2 = df_merge2[(df_merge2['retweeting_id'] == 822215673812119553  )] to generate the dataframe. And I cant just add one because it messes up the other smaller numbers it works correctly for.